# How to set custom app bar button icons in windows 8

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I want to set my own customs app bar icons which I downloaded . How can I set that this doesnot work

```
<AppBarButton x:Name="save" Click="save_Click" Label="Save" Icon="Assets/icon/1.png" />
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try adding it this way:

```
<AppBarButton Label="BitmapIcon" Click="AppBarButton_Click">
    <AppBarButton.Icon>
        <BitmapIcon UriSource="ms-appx:///Assets/icon/1.png"/>
    </AppBarButton.Icon>
</AppBarButton>
```

Check also if the path is correct and that the image is in the correct format to be displayed.
You could also give a try using Blend to check if the image is working.

Comment: I am doing it in this manner but my image is pixelated, I have used images of size mentioned in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28935766/appbar-button-icon-not-fitting-inside-elipse

Comment: I think this may be the wrong question to ask about it. Anyhow, what's your image size?

Comment: see the image in answer of the question

Answer (score 0):

Go back to basics, by creating a button from scratch, and animating it with Blend. I spent days tweaking the code for custom buttons and never got it right. In the end I spent a morning doing the tutorials, and then I was moving ahead. Both of these are very good: [Make a Styled Button in XAML for Universal Windows Apps](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30199.make-a-styled-button-in-xaml-for-universal-windows-apps.aspx) and [Custom Styles in XAML - Edit Button Style to Create Your Own Custom Style](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7NUSnj8WoQw). The second one is targetted to phone apps, but with some minor changes at the start can be used for desktop – Stephen Hosking 20 secs ago   edit