# AppBar button icon not fitting inside elipse

Tags: icons, windows-phone-8.1, appbar

Hey I am creating bottom app bar and adding 3, app bar button to it like shown below. One use inbuilt  icon and the other two uses Bitmap icons

```
<AppBarButton>
<AppBarButton.Icon>
    <BitmapIcon UriSource="ms-appx:///Assets/Like.png" Height="20" Width="20"/>
</AppBarButton.Icon>
```

AppBarButton with bitmap icons display correctly in the design view, that is enclosed within the eclipse of appbar button. But when I deploy it on my phone the app bar button looks like below (two on the right)

https://s24.postimg.org/q3yg74gx1/wp_ss_20150309_0002.jpg

[image: Wrong render of appbar button]

What is wron with it

Comment: What's the size of your icons? Does it fit to the [guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/windows/apps/hh465302.aspx)?

Comment: I've resized them to 10x10 pixels. The only difference is that the icon in app has become more blur.

Comment: Have you left the appropriate padding?

Comment: Maybe not. I'll check it asap as I reach home.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you may have forgotten about appropriate padding - more information [at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/windows/apps/hh465302.aspx):

> [image: paddig of app bar]

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to find default Windows Phone icons in Microsoft SDKs folder on your PC. In my case it's `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.1\Icons\Light`. There you can check how to correctly prepare icons for your application bar. 
[image: icons]

They must be **76 x 76** PNG images (including **padding**) with alpha channel.